# How to extract JSON values that does not have attribute names?

Tags: json, talend, jsonpath

```
{
 "A1":{
       "name":"Ad hoc",
       "projectId":0
      },
 "X2":{
       "name":"BBB",
       "projectId":101
        },
 "AB":{
       "name":"CCC",
       "projectId":102
        },
 "recordsCount":3
 }
```

For this JSON, how to extract values? i need output like,

```
 A1, Ad hoc
 X2, BBB
 AB, CCC
```

experts inputs appreciated.

Comment: add some code that you have tried.

Comment: i tried $[*]..name but i do not know how to get A1, X2, AB values.

Comment: Sachin Gupta, if you know the answer, please help. I need to use the Json path in Talend to extract the parent value A1, X2, AB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis**

*XPath* can't read unnamed attributes. It will always result in an exception. If you want to get the values, you need to use *JsonPath*.

**Solution**

Even then, it makes sense to add surrounding brackets, otherwise the first level will be consumed as well:

```
[
    {
 "A1":{
       "name":"Ad hoc",
       "projectId":0
      },
 "X2":{
       "name":"BBB",
       "projectId":101
        },
 "AB":{
       "name":"CCC",
       "projectId":102
        },
 "recordsCount":3
    }
]
```

You can try the correct query on [jsonpath.com](http://jsonpath.com/). For me (with the additional brackets) the path `$.*` worked.

To extract the values, you need to use a **tExtractJSONFields** component in Talend if using a file or REST request.

A valid `JSON query` could be easily `[0]` for the field with alphanumeric identifiers.